# How to read pod information in dockerfile

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a requirement where I have to read information about pods such as podname, attachedvolume name etc and pass it onto the DockerFile which will write this information inside the container configuration files.
This docker image is part of the same pod spec which will get downloaded.

Comment: Are you sure you need to pass these values to Dockerfile, are you going some nested deployment?

Comment: I have elasticsearch image.I want to make datanodes awszone aware. In order to do that, I am going to introduce an attribute so that the shards are zone aware.
Inside this docker image, there is the yaml file which will create 2 data nodes in 2 zones. Since this deployment will create 2 pods, I want to pass two different names to the yaml.I hope the question is clear .

Comment: This is impossible, since the image is a static artifact that gets built and pushed to a registry, and later referenced in a Kubernetes YAML spec.  You should look into Kubernetes' other configuration mechanisms, and whether a resource like a StatefulSet that produces more predictable names is helpful to you.

Comment: You have to use environment variables and pass them into a configuration.

Comment: yeah kinda made it halfway through.thanks

Comment: Just one confusion. I am using elasticsearch 6.7 and following this guide : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/allocation-awareness.html ... My confusion is 
the following 2 attributes needs to be set only in master nodes for sharding? 
node.attr.rack_id: rack_one>>
cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes: rack_id>>>

Answer (score 2):

If you need to pass information about pod into a configuration file you can use [environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#use-pod-fields-as-values-for-environment-variables) or [Downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/#the-downward-api).